# Valores com base no último dia de cada mês (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel

Editado:

Pessoal, esse é meu arquivo de Excel. Eu quero o ultimo valor de cada mês da coluna A seja referenciado pela coluna C, ou seja, para o mês e ano de cada linha da coluna A devo encontrar o valor do que seria referente ao último dia desse mesmo mês e ano, pegando o valor que está nesta linha na coluna D..

Por PROCV consigo fazer?

```
 A           B      C          D
30/12/1988  1,8085  30/12/1988  1,8027
31/01/1989  1,7500  31/01/1989  1,7479
28/02/1989  1,7440  28/02/1989  1,739101
31/03/1989  1,6852  31/03/1989  1,6819
28/04/1989  1,6890  28/04/1989  1,6858
31/05/1989  1,5715  31/05/1989  1,564201
30/06/1989  1,5490  30/06/1989  1,543899
31/07/1989  1,6660  31/07/1989  1,6583
31/08/1989  1,5730  31/08/1989  1,5617
29/09/1989  1,6145  28/09/1989  1,605299
31/10/1989  1,5775  27/10/1989  1,5723
30/11/1989  1,5695  30/11/1989  1,5628
29/12/1989  1,6145  29/12/1989  1,6031
31/01/1990  1,6794  31/01/1990  1,6695
28/02/1990  1,6892  28/02/1990  1,667699
30/03/1990  1,6480  30/03/1990  1,6384
30/04/1990  1,6389  30/04/1990  1,632197
31/05/1990  1,6765  31/05/1990  1,668499
29/06/1990  1,7450  29/06/1990  1,739399
31/07/1990  1,8600  31/07/1990  1,852199
31/08/1990  1,8920  31/08/1990  1,8844
28/09/1990  1,8735  27/09/1990  1,8693
31/10/1990  1,9440  31/10/1990  1,934101
30/11/1990  1,9392  28/11/1990  1,9588
31/12/1990  1,9285  31/12/1990  1,9192
31/01/1991  1,9650  31/01/1991  1,9564
28/02/1991  1,9100  28/02/1991  1,903115
29/03/1991  1,7485  28/03/1991  1,732099
30/04/1991  1,7225  30/04/1991  1,7174
31/05/1991  1,6980  31/05/1991  1,690332
28/06/1991  1,6180  28/06/1991  1,614698
31/07/1991  1,6845  31/07/1991  1,679599
30/08/1991  1,6800  30/08/1991  1,6743
30/09/1991  1,7520  30/09/1991  1,7436
31/10/1991  1,7425  31/10/1991  1,7324
29/11/1991  1,7655  29/11/1991  1,759256
31/12/1991  1,8660  31/12/1991  1,860501
31/01/1992  1,7890  31/01/1992  1,7783
28/02/1992  1,7560  28/02/1992  1,7491
31/03/1992  1,7363  31/03/1992  1,7272
30/04/1992  1,7750  30/04/1992  1,766502
29/05/1992  1,8290  29/05/1992  1,8206
30/06/1992  1,9035  30/06/1992  1,894701
31/07/1992  1,9200  31/07/1992  1,916501

...
```

Alguma ajuda/intuição?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diogo, **resolva assim**:

Na coluna **F** coloque a **fórmula abaixo** para cada linha de sua tabela

```
=DATA(SE(MÊS(A1)=12;ANO(A1)+1;ANO(A1));SE(MÊS(A1)=12;1;MÊS(A1)+1);1)-1
```

Ela pega o **mês** e **ano** da coluna **A** da respectiva linha (neste caso, a linha 1) e gera **a última data do mês correspondente**.

Por exemplo:

```
dez/88         31/12/1988

jan/89         31/01/1989
```

Coloque a **fórmula abaixo** na coluna **E** e pronto!

```
=PROCV(F1;C1:D80;2;VERDADEIRO)
```

O **VERDADEIRO** faz com que ele **pare a busca na resposta exata** ou no valor imediatamente anterior a um valor superior ao procurado (complicado, né?), **caso não haja resposta exata**.

Se precisar tratar a busca, use o **SE** com o mesmo **PROCV** dentro, e se der certo repita o **PROCV** na parte da resposta correta para ele por o valor encontrado pelo **PROCV**, senão, coloque "**branco**" ou uma **mensagem que não achou a data correspondente** na parte não verdadeira da resposta (do comando **SE**).

**Coloque a faixa de busca apropriada para você!**

Funcionou amigo?

Comment: Oi, Leo! Eu editei a pergunta. Consegui organizar melhor, acho que ficou até mais claro. Na maneira que você sugeriu consigo fazer?

Comment: Fiz o PROCV para você. Vou postar, olha o boi!...

Comment: Valeu, Léo! Funcionou demais! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Por nada, bom trabalho!

Answer (score 1):

Fala Diogo!

Não sei se entendi muito bem o que você quer. Veja se eu entendi certo:
Você quer que o valor da E1 (E2,E3,E* e etc) seja sempre o último valor da D1 (D2,D3,D* e etc)?

Se for isso, basta inserir na coluna E1 (E2,E3,E* e etc) a formula:

> =right(D1,1)
>   =right(D2,1)
>   =right(D3,1)
>   =right(D*,1)
>   etc..

Caso você queira que o valor da E1 (E2,E3,E* e etc), seja sempre o valor da célula acima, apenas troque o "D2" pelo "D1". Porem você teria que começar da segunda linha.

> =right(D1,1) *erro* 
>   =right(D1,1)
>   =right(D2,1)
>   =right(D*,1)
>   etc..

Caso você tenha uma lista dos valores do meses dez/88; jan/89; fev/89; e etc, ai você irá precisar do procv na sheet de cada mês e utilizar a função maior() (ou max())  em uma coluna ao lado e apontar pra sua lista.

> =VLOOKUP(A1;'Página2'!A:E;5;0) "*essa formula entra na E1 da 'Aba 1'* "
>   =MAX(D:D) "*essa formula ficaria na 'Aba 2' ao lado do valor D1 (por exemplo)*"

Aonde foi seleciona uma área de A ate E, aonde em E deve ser colocado o MAX() da coluna D;
Veja: https://goo.gl/tQwC29

Para ver a lista de conversão de formulas do excel de ENG e PT:
https://usuariosdoexcel.wordpress.com/lista-de-funcoes-do-excel/

Por acaso é alguma das três opções ? Caso contrário, fala ae! :)

Comment: A ideia é fazer o procv mesmo. O que eu quero é que na primeira celula da coluna E1 o meu procv procure na coluna D1 o ultimo valor associado ao mês da primeira celula de A1. Na segunda celula da coluna E1 esse procv me devolveria o ultimo valor da coluna D1 associado ao mês da segunda celula da coluna A1 e assim por diante.

Comment: Valeu pelos outros comandos, acabei percebendo que irei precisar deles em outro momento. Valeu!